# OpenCart - Can I access data externally?

Tags: opencart

I have a project in mind for a desktop aplication that interacts with e-shops directly.  My goal is to create an application that uses the e-shop´s table and presents it to the shop through this app.
Before I get too into it I want to find a shoping cart software (preferably the oneclick installs that many webhosts offer) that will let me access it´s tables and modify/read/write at will without going throught the website.
Could I do this with OpenCart?
if not which way should I shoot?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Normally this is not possible unless You'd stick directly with some DB administration tool that will connect directly to the database server. There are some options though:

- write an API for the desktop application - it could be based on web services - that the desktop application will comunicate with (more work has to be done but this should be the best solution)
- let the desktop application connect directly to the database server (the same settings as OpenCart uses; requires only the desktop application development)
- or as I mentioned, use a desktop DBMS tool for MySQL (or one that is universal), there are plenty of them, many also free... (no development at all but I'm not sure if this  would be the desired solution)

Comment: Thanks! My plan was to access the DBfiles directly throught server and use them the same way Opencart would.